# Django, loop over all form errors

Tags: django, django-forms

At my template, I want to iterate through all form errors, including the ones that are NOT belonging to a specific field. ( which means for form.errors, it should also display for `__all__` errors aswell)

I have tried several versions, Ie:

```
 <div id="msg">
  {% if form.errors %}
  <div class="error">
   <p><span>ERROR</span></p>
   <ul>
   {% for key,value in form.errors %}
    {% for error in value %}
     <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
 </div>
```

Still no achievement, I will be greatful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Form errors in Django are implemented as an `ErrorDict` instance (which is just a subclass of `dict` with extras). Try a slight adjustment to your template for loop syntax:

```
{% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
```

Answer (score 19):

Are you, by any chance, looking for [`form.non_field_errors`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#ref-forms-validation)? That is how you would get access to the errors that aren't associated with a particular field.

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
<ul>
    {{ form.non_field_errors.as_ul }}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Check the [forms.py test suite](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/tests/regressiontests/forms/forms.py) as well for another example. Search for `form.non_field_errors`