# Display error if there is error in fields

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Im trying to raise error for empty fields or fields which are not validating in form
so Im doing this method below but I know this is not the best way...

**views.py :**

```
'KnowledgeForm': form,
'errors': str(form.errors),
```

but then in Django-template I have to use `if` for each field and im adding custom name for each field , i dont know why i cant use Verbose_name...

**Template :**

```
                    {% if errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>
                            {% if KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeTitle %}
                            عنوان دانش: {{ KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeTitle }}
                            {% endif %}
            
                            {% if KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeTextSummary %}
                             Summary: {{ KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeTextSummary }}
                            {% endif %}
            
                            {% if KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeFromDate %}
                            from Date: {{ KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeFromDate }}
                            {% endif %}
            
                            {% if KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgetoDate %}
                           To date : {{ KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgetoDate }}
                            {% endif %}
            
                            {% if KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeProcess %}
                            Chart: {{ KnowledgeForm.errors.KnowledgeProcess }}
                            {% endif %}
            
                          {% endif %}

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
```

**Second method :**

```
                    {% if KnowledgeForm.errors %}
                        <ul class="alert alert-danger">
                        {% for key,value in KnowledgeForm.errors.items %} 
                        <li>{{ key|escape }} : {{ value|escape }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
```

in this method i get the name based on whats used in models.py how can i change it?

Comment: What is your variable `KnowledgeForm` in your template ?

Comment: its equal to form , i edited the post check it out

Comment: Intead of adding each field name you can loop on each field to access errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django, loop over all form errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462522/django-loop-over-all-form-errors)

Comment: check my second method in post i updated my question... i cant get the verbose name for them while i have used verbose name for each field in models.py @AnkitTiwari

Comment: You don't have to pass extra context `'errors': str(form.errors),` if you're passing `form` becouse you've access to errors in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most clear and concise way is to use a `forloop`

Try replacing your entire `if` block in your HTML with the below code

```html
{% for field in KnowledgeForm %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
             {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
    {% endf %}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't think you need `'errors': str(form.errors),`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you convert errors to str and you don't need to separate this.

## In your template:

```
# if you want to use verbose_name just use label_tag.
# label_tag is equal to your verbose name.

{% for field in KnowledgeForm %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So you have the error top of input