# DJANGO {{form.errors.title.as_text}} not working

Tags: html, django

a I have been watching a video which uses the following code to show errors.

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{form.errors.title.as_text}}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

But when I use it no errors show

If I use:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {% for error in form.errors %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I get a single word eg. 'email' but the whole error text does not display.

It works fine on the video,

Could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What does it give you without the `.as_text`? Maybe something you could iterate over? :) Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors

Comment: Nothing at all!

Comment: Is there an error that should be displayed at that time for that field?

Comment: yes, an email format error

Comment: using  {{ form.errors.as_data}}  returns {'email': [ValidationError(['Enter a valid email address.'])]}  which is better, but not sure how to parse the bit I want from the dictionary.

Comment: Cromwell you should be able to access it like any other dictionary in the template. Lets loop over the inner list that belongs to the key. `{% for error in form.errors.title %}{{error}}{%endfor%}` Otherwise, this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462625/18020941

Comment: I did try that at one point but was getting just the key, but have finally got a working version, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, imaged to get it to work using:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
        {{ value.as_text }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks for your help